# How to hide (and not toggle) the toolbar in a RCP-Plugin-Product?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to hide the toolbar in a RCP-Plugin-Product. 
I added this code to my perspective:

```
        IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .getService(IHandlerService.class);
    if (service != null) {
        try {
            service.executeCommand("org.eclipse.ui.ToggleCoolbarAction", null);
        } catch (ExecutionException | NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException
                | NotHandledException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            StatusManager.getManager()
                    .handle(new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Perspective.PLUGIN_ID, "Error while hiding toolbar", e));
        }
    } else {
        StatusManager.getManager()
                .handle(new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Perspective.PLUGIN_ID, "IHandlerService is null"));
    }
```

Executing my product the toolbar is still visible and I got this error:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotEnabledException: Trying to execute the disabled command org.eclipse.ui.ToggleCoolbarAction
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:485)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:353)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:340)
at bdd.klighd.Perspective.createInitialLayout(Perspective.java:79)...
```

Avoiding this error I put the code to another class of my RCP-Plugin and after that the toolbar was hidden while executing my product.

But when I executed my product again the toolbar was visible; the visibilty of my toolbar is toggling.

I would like to hide the toolbar, not a toggling toolbar.
Does anybody have an idea how to hide the toolbar programmatically?

Comment: The APIs for this are in **internal** classes and are therefore should not be used.

Comment: @greg-449: okay, thanks. But is there another way to hide the toolbar?

Comment: If you write an RCP with its own window configurer you can set it there, otherwise I don't think so.

Comment: @greg-449: I was able to hide the menubar via `hiddenMenuItem` in `perspectiveExtensions` in the `plugin.xml` of the plugin. Is there a way to do it for the toolbar, too? Otherwise do you know a good tutorial how to write an own window configurer?

Comment: There is just the hiddenToolBarItem as described in the documentation. You don't write the configurer, the existing `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer` is available in the RCP `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`.